# Python: adding to a list from different function

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, addition

I already posted a similar question but I did not get the correct answer, maybe because I was not very clear about the way I expect my program to run.

I am writing a simple gift adding program and I want to add a gift to a person that is in a dictionary in a different function.

```
def main():

    print("Select: ")

    print("\n\n\t1. Gifts")

    selection_1 = input()

    if selection_1 == "1":
        people_list()
        return selection

    else:
        print("Type a number for selecting.")
        main()

def people_list():

    people = {"Elena":["book","candy","sweater"],
             "Daria":["healthy food"],
             "Petra and Rok":[],
             "Nikola":["cheese"],
             "Matija + Elena":["vacation"],
             "Christian":["chocolate"]}

    print ("""Select a person to show their gifts:

        1. Elena
        2. Daria
        3. Petra and Rok
        4. Nikola
        5. Matija + Elena
        6. Christian

    """)
    gifts(people)


def gifts(people):

    selection_2 = input()

    if selection_2 == "1":
        person = people["Elena"]
        print(people["Elena"])
        manage_gifts(person, people)
        return person
    elif selection_2 == "2":
        person = people["Daria"]
        print(people["Daria"])
        manage_gifts(person, people)
        return person
    elif selection_2 == "3":
        person = people["Petra and Rok"]
        print(people["Petra and Rok"])
        manage_gifts(person, people)
        return person
    elif selection_2 == "4":
        person = people["Nikola"]
        print(people["Nikola"])
        manage_gifts(person, people)
        return person
    elif selection_2 == "5":
        person = people["Matija + Elena"]
        print(people["Matija + Elena"])
        manage_gifts(person, people)
        return person
    elif selection_2 == "6":
        person = people["Christian"]
        print(people["Christian"])
        manage_gifts(person, people)
        return person
    else:
        print("Choose a person from the list!")
        people_list()
    return person

def manage_gifts(person, people):


    print("""
        1. Add gift""")

    gift_option = input()

    if gift_option == "1":
        print("\nType the gift you would like to add?\n")
        new_gift = input()
        people[person].append(str(new_gift))
        print("Gift added: ", people[person])

main()
```

I want to achive that the new gift is added to the 'person' I select from the list.
The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python/Vaje_Book/Gifts.py", line 92, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:/Python/Vaje_Book/Gifts.py", line 10, in main
    people_list()
  File "E:/Python/Vaje_Book/Gifts.py", line 36, in people_list
    gifts(people)
  File "E:/Python/Vaje_Book/Gifts.py", line 46, in gifts
    manage_gifts(person, people)
  File "E:/Python/Vaje_Book/Gifts.py", line 89, in manage_gifts
    people[person].append(str(new_gift))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: you should get the value in some new variable list  and then append the new_gift and then update it back. BTW if you want to pass the dictionary then use ** in arguments where the function manage_gift is defined.

Comment: From what I can gather, you want to change things like `person = people["Elena"]` in `gifts()` to just `person = "Elena"` etc. You want `person` to be just a name for you to look up in `people`. Instead, `people['Elena']` is giving you back the gifts they already have.

Answer (score 0):

In `gifts(people)`:
when you do `person = people["Elena"]`, then `person` is of list type.

Then in `manage_gifts(person, people)`:
when you do `people[person].append(str(new_gift))`, then the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` is logically raised because person is a list. It should be a string.

I think that in `gifts(people)`, one should replace `person = people["Elena"]` with `person = "Elena"`. And so on for the other assignments of `person` variable.

However there are other mistakes to fix in this code:
- don't call `main()` inside `main()`
- don't return anything in `main()`